# A pair of campus riddles

Tags: riddle, knowledge

The answers to these riddles are places, people, or things in University of Maryland. To make the riddles fair for everyone, consult these resources: [Campus map](https://maps.umd.edu/map/), [Stamp map](https://stamp.umd.edu/the_stamp_student_union/directions_to_stamp/building_map).

1. Name this place where it is a 4.0 in terms of its letter grade, boring is something that it ain't, half of it is a place where music is made, and it holds underground paint.
2. I used to be your Aunt, I was half of the name Annabelle, but how? But I'm a different food in Stamp, who am I now?

Hints will be added later if these are too tough.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer (because my first guess on 1 turned out to be wrong):

2.

I used to be your Aunt, I was half of the name Annabelle, but how?

> This is probably a reference to Auntie Anne's.

But I'm a different food in Stamp, who am I now?

> It's mainly known for its **pretzels** (Auntie Anne's Pretzels).

Comment: In the US rot13(n 4.0 pbeerfcbaqf gb na N abg n O. Guvf vf pbasvezrq ba gur HZQ fvgr urer:) https://registrar.umd.edu/current/Policies/acadregs.html

Comment: There goes the first one then.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st is

> Studio A

because

> A is a 4.0, music is made in a studio, Studio A is on the basement floor, and you can paint there. Is the line about "boring" there for the rhyme?